# Query to calculate end date based on provide only date column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have achieved my requirement for calculating end date based on provided in date column. Let me explain with example. I had two column 1) ACCT_NO and 2) AUD_IN.

So I have to add AUD_END column based on next row of AUD_IN date. For example my data as below.

```
ACCT_NO | AUD_IN |
------------------
A0001   |23-06-01
A0001   |22-01-04
A0001   |09-09-06
A0002   |14-02-02
A0002   |07-07-09
A0003   |19-08-08
```

My actual requirement output was as below.

```
ACCT_NO | AUD_IN | AUD_END
--------------------------
A0001   |23-06-01|21-01-04
A0001   |22-01-04|08-09-06
A0001   |09-09-06| null
A0002   |14-02-02|06-07-09
A0002   |07-07-09| null
A0003   |19-08-08| null
```

So I have achieve above thing with help of ORACLE LEAD function as below:

```
SELECT ACCT_NO,
AUD_IN,
(LEAD (AUD_IN,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NO ORDER BY AUD_IN))-1 AS AUD_END
FROM XYZ
ORDER BY ACCT_NO,AUD_IN;
```

Comment: What is your question?  You seem to have solved your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to [ask and answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), because you had a problem and figured out how to solve it? If so that's fine but it should still be presented as a separate question and answer, not with the resolution within the question. However, there are a lot of examples of how to do this already, so I'm not sure if this will be more useful to other people than what is already available.